# Domain in a fields.function field

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo

I want to get the ids, so i do:

```
self.search(cr, uid, [('test','=',10)], context=context)
```

The problem is that test is a fields.function.It returns all the ids, instead of the ids with the domain applied.
The function of the test(_get_value) works fine.If i browse each id, the 'test' field has the correct result.
What can i do to get back the ids with this domain applied?

```
'test': fields.function(_get_value, type='integer','Test')
```

So the question is: How can i get the correct ids with a domain applied, when the domain's field is a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a `function` field in a domain, you have to be sure that the field is stored in the database.

By default, `function` fields are not stored in the database. To store them, you must indicate that this way:

```
'test': fields.function(_get_value, type='integer', store=True, 'Test'),
```

**EDIT**

Or instead of passing `True` to the parameter `store`, you can pass a dictionary if you need the field `test` to be updated depending on some conditions.

Comment: You are right.It is not saved in the database.But instead of store=True, i give a dictionary store={'object_class':
                                                           (_get_value,['test'],10)}. Now it is working

Comment: Both methods (passing `True` or a dictionary to `store` parameter) store the function field in the database. The diference is that with `store=True` the field `test` will never be updated. If you pass a dictionary, `test` will be able to change depending on the content of the dictionary you pass to it :)

Comment: Yes exactly.The field test will be updated every day.So the dictionary works best for me. :D

Comment: I added the part of the dictionary to the answer. Don't forget to set the answer as correct, if it was helpful for you, to close the question ;)